# Remote desktop - disconnect VPN?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a VPN server on which I created 2 account for my notebooks. I connect both to the VPN and they get an IP automatically. Both run Windows 7 and are able to do multiple logins.

I log off system number 1 to remote control this machine using system number 2. When I use remote desktop to control system number 1 and enter user and pass on system 2, as soon as I see the welcome message the VPN and WiFi on system number 2 are disconnected and remote desktop loses connection as well.

I believe if I get my wireless connection to use "keep alive" along with VPN connection there should be no problems. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Keep alive is likely **not** the problem. If you needed that then the VPN connection would die if you did not use it for a period of time. Instead it happens every time you something specific, which means that that action is likely to trigger the problem.